# Disable Microsoft Edge Pop-up Notifications in Taskbar and System Tray

Tags: taskbar, notification-area, microsoft-edge, popups

I recently started seeing popup notifications from Microsoft Edge when I try to open another browser like Firefox or Chrome:

[image: Microsoft Edge is safer than Firefox taskbar popup]

[image: Chrome is draining your battery faster switch to Microsoft Edge]

[image: Earn more with Microsoft Edge]

Is there any way to disable these popups without [uninstalling Microsoft Edge](https://superuser.com/questions/949814/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-microsoft-edge-in-windows-10)?

Comment: Windows 10 is 167% more annoying than the previous version..?

Answer (score 28):

According to [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/279632/how-to-stop-microsoft-edges-pop-up-notifications/) these advertisements can be disabled in the Windows 10 Settings:

> They’re not generated by the Microsoft Edge app on your PC. Instead,
>   they’re generated by the Windows operating system itself.
>
> You’ll find this setting in the Settings app. Open the Start menu and
>   click the Settings icon to launch it.
>
> Navigate to System > Notifications & Actions in the Settings app.
>
> Scroll down to the Notifications section and disable the **“Get tips,
>   tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows”** option.

[image: Disable Microsoft Edge Pop-up Notifications and Ads]

Comment: You submitted your answer to quickly for me.  <sad face>

Comment: Also available via the registry:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager]
"SoftLandingEnabled"=dword:00000000

Comment: doesn't work. can't we get a real answer!